# angular-google-maps causes "TypeError: undefined is not a function" with angularjs 1.3

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I've implemented a very basic map using the [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) module. After the page has finished processing all scripts, I will always find a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" logged in the Chrome Developer Tools console, even though everything seems to work as expected.

It happens when `$scope.control.getGMap().fitBounds($scope.bounds);` is called within the `uiGmapIsReady` promise function.

```
angular.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])


.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: 3.17,
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
})

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 'uiGmapIsReady', function ($scope, $timeout, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, uiGmapIsReady) {

    $scope.markers = [
        { latitude: 33.970675, longitude: -118.454618},
        { latitude: 33.980675, longitude: -118.454618},
        { latitude: 33.974246, longitude: -118.455458}
    ]

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        $scope.bounds = new maps.LatLngBounds();
        angular.forEach($scope.markers, function (value, key) {
            var myLatLng = new maps.LatLng($scope.markers[key].latitude, $scope.markers[key].longitude);
            $scope.bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        });
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: $scope.bounds.getCenter().lat(), longitude: $scope.bounds.getCenter().lng() }, zoom: 5 };
        $scope.map.options = { MapTypeId: maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID };

    });

    $scope.control = {};

    uiGmapIsReady.promise().then((function (maps) {
        $scope.control.getGMap().fitBounds($scope.bounds);
    }));

    $scope.refreshMap = function () {
        $scope.control.refresh({ latitude: $scope.bounds.getCenter().lat(), longitude: $scope.bounds.getCenter().lng() });
    }

    $scope.streetZoom = function () {
        $scope.control.getGMap().setZoom(14);
    }
}])
```

And here is the markup

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
        center="map.center" 
        zoom="map.zoom" 
        options="map.options"
        control="control">
        <ui-gmap-marker idkey="$index" coords="item" ng-repeat="item in markers track by $index">
            <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" closeclick="closeClick()">
                <p class="google-window">{{item.latitude}}, {{item.longitude}}</p>
            </ui-gmap-window>
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And here is the error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function             angular.js:11655
```

Any insight as to why this happens would greatly be appreciated! I feel like I've broken something and don't know why.

Comment: I believe this is where getGMap is undefined, $scope.control.getGMap

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: I have figured out the problem. Within `index.html` I had a `ng-controller="MainController"` attribute set. And I also has routing configured on a separate file. So that was causing the controller to be loaded on bootstrap and on route configuration. I took out the ng-controller attribute from my markup and now all is working well.